# Question about combining pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes from .csv files, and I am combining them based on a common col name they share, "NAME" and what I am trying to do is display the differences of two of the factors on another column. However the error I get is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\nhoss\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2891, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 70, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 101, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1675, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1683, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: '\ufeff2010'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\nhoss\OneDrive\Desktop\Senior_Project\responserate.py", line 22, in <module>
    combinedresponse['DIFFERENCE'] = combinedresponse['\ufeff2010'] - combinedresponse['2000']
  File "C:\Users\nhoss\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2902, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "C:\Users\nhoss\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2893, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: '\ufeff2010'
[Finished in 0.933s]
```

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import string

response2000 = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\nhoss\OneDrive\Desktop\Senior_Project\2000ResponseRates.csv', skiprows=0)

pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.width', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)

response2010 = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\nhoss\OneDrive\Desktop\Senior_Project\responserate2010.csv', skiprows=0 )
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.width', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)

combinedresponse = response2000.merge(response2010, on='NAME', how='inner')
combinedresponse['DIFFERENCE'] = combinedresponse['﻿2010'] - combinedresponse['2000']
print(combinedresponse)
```

The CSV Files:

responserate2010.csv

```
2010,NAME,STATE,COUNTY_ID
52,Allegany County,36,3
64,Bronx County,36,5
68,Broome County,36,7
57,Cattaraugus County,36,9
64,Cayuga County,36,11
61,Chautauqua County,36,13
71,Chemung County,36,15
58,Chenango County,36,17
62,Clinton County,36,19
50,Columbia County,36,21
67,Cortland County,36,23
50,Delaware County,36,25
66,Dutchess County,36,27
70,Erie County,36,29
63,Fulton County,36,35
52,Essex County,36,31
59,Franklin County,36,33
```

2000ResponseRates.csv:

```
SS,CCC,NAME,2000
36,001,Albany County,70
36,003005,Allegany County,60
36,005,Bronx County,56
36,007,Broome County,72
36,009,Cattaraugus County,64
36,011,Cayuga County,60
36,013,Chautauqua County,66
36,015,Chemung County,75
36,017,Chenango County,65
36,019,Clinton County,68
36,021,Columbia County,62
36,023,Cortland County,64
36,025,Delaware County,53
36,027,Dutchess County,68
36,029,Erie County,74
36,031,Essex County,58
36,033,Franklin County,67
```

Comment: Seems like your `responserate2010.csv` file might have some formatting issue. It might be reading the strings in another encoding style?

Answer (score 0):

Please try as below:

```
combinedresponse  = pd.merge(respose2000, response2010, on="NAME", how="inner)
combinedresponse['DIFFERENCE'] = combinedresponse['2010'] - combinedresponse['2000']
```